# Retrieve the attributes of a row which has the maximum value for a column

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following relation `Invoice`:

```
Invoice
-------------------------------------
| Id | Country | Total | CustomerId |
-------------------------------------
| 1  | USA     | 22.32 | 3          |
-------------------------------------
| 2  | Belgium | 12.18 | 4          |
-------------------------------------
| 3  | USA     | 27.76 | 2          |
-------------------------------------
| 4  | France  | 24.52 | 5          |
-------------------------------------
| 5  | USA     | 14.29 | 3          |
-------------------------------------
```

I have to query the attributes `Id` and `Total` of the invoice, which has the highest value for `Total` and `Country` USA. If there are more than one invoices from USA with the same maximum value, all of them have to be returned in the result set.

What I have so far is as follows:

```
SELECT
   i."Id",
   i."Total"
FROM 
   public."Invoice" i
WHERE
   i."Total" = (SELECT MAX(t."Total") 
                   FROM public."Invoice" t 
                   WHERE t."Country" = 'USA');
```

Is this the right way to do it? I am not sure, because I do not check in the subquery if `i.Id = t.Id`. If I do this, I get more than one row in the result. How do I make sure that the value that is returned by the subquery actually belongs to the `i`?

Answer (score 6):

A simple way is to just get the US invoices, order by total (descending) and take the top value;

```
SELECT * 
FROM invoice i
WHERE country = 'USA'
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 1
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ce928/1).

If you have multiple invoices with the same total and want them all, you can instead use a common table expression to rank them by total (descending) and get all highest ranked invoices;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY total DESC) rank FROM invoice i
  WHERE country = 'USA'
)
SELECT id, country, total, customerid
FROM cte WHERE rank=1;
```

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a71ff/1).

Comment: What happens if you have the same maximum value for more than one US invoice? This solution always returns one row, right?

Comment: Yes. Sorry I forgot to mention that. I will edit the answer right now.

Comment: What do you think about my solution? Is it correct? It does give me what I want, but I'm confused because I don't check for the ID in the subquery.

Comment: @Djihad The problem with your solution is that if the top total for US is $57, you'll also return all $57 invoices from Dubai. That is, you find the max for the US, but get _any_ invoice with the same value. To correct it, you could add `AND i.country='USA'` to the outer query too.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. I didn't think about that. But unfortunately, I cannot use you second solution. I'm not allowed to use `DENSE_RANK()`.

Comment: @Djihad Any version restriction on PostgreSQL that prevents it, or some other non technical reason?

Comment: A reason of non-technical nature.

Comment: @Djihad Well, then this is the best I can do without knowing all limitations :) If your query - with the addition of the country condition in the outer query - will work for the purpose, I suggest you use that.